# If ajax post success redirect user to new flask route

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to have my user redirect after submitting but I keep getting ajax failed.

```
          $.ajax({
            url: '/testing',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'post',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
              success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
              // ajax success callback
            }, error: function (response) {
              alert('ajax failed');
              // ajax error callback
            },
          });
        });
```

Here are my flask routes

```
@app.route('/testing', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def testing():
    return url_for('results')

@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Why not use a form, that's what forms do, redirect after submission ?

Comment: This is a simplifed version, I am pulling variables in jquery from user slider positions.  What would you suggest as a form though, the data variable countains a string of numbers.

Comment: @JohnS Those two edits worked! Thank you

Comment: Try changing the dataType value to 'text' and see what happens. I suspect you are not returning valid JSON, so JQuery is calling the error handler. To be valid JSON, you should return a string that looks like `{ "url": "/xxx/xxx" }`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify `dataType: 'json``, JQuery will attempt to parse the response into a JavaScript object (or array) before passing it to the success handler. If the response is not valid JSON, JQuery calls the error handler.

If you are returning something like the following, it is not valid JSON:

```
/xxxx/xxxx
```

Valid JSON could look like this:

```
{ "url" : "/xxx/xxx" }
```

Another alternative would be to change to `dataType: 'text'`. In that case, JQuery will not parse the response before calling the success handler. It will just pass the response text to the success handler.